# Large Bodies Of Water?

Tags: sound-design, water

Hi there,

Wanted to know if you have any tips for making sea & ocean sounds? I live too far from the sea to actually go and record there.

I've played around with filtering noise and got some fairly ok results but I need to layer a few more things on top.

I've heard pouring carbonated drink out on concrete sounds quite good?

Thanks!

edit- realise I've been very vague. I am re-making the sound for this video, so need everything to sound quite colossal: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQ72d8xYqqQ

another edit- Just out of interest how do you think the sound at the start of this video was made? http://vimeo.com/31373936
That freezing effect sounds really nice.

Comment: @dominic , shoot me an email


Answer (score 2):

Seagulls always help sell the ocean.

What is important is what perspective you want to portray. Do you want intimate wave lappings on a lake shore? Or do you want large waves of an ocean as if you're standing on the beach? Or do you want distant waves as if you're standing in an alley near the ocean? I think your answer is a tad bit general because there is a vast difference in approach if you want any of those 3 and there are infinite variations of the above.

As an easy way out, you can search for boutique ocean libraries. Tim Prebble over at Hiss and a Roar released a great one with ocean sounds.

Comment: @utopia. Reading back, yes you're right, I've added the video in the edit. Thanks